# Partitioning a superset and getting the list of original sets for each partition

Tags: algorithm, python-3.x, categories, categorization

## Introduction

While trying to do some cathegorization on nodes in a graph (which will be rendered differenty), I find myself confronted with the following problem:

## The Problem

Given a superset of elements `S = {0, 1, ... M}` and a number `n` of **non-disjoint** subsets `T_i` thereof, with `0 <= i < n`, what is the best algorithm to find out the partition of the set `S` called `P`?

`P = S` is the union of all **disjoint** partitions `P_j` of the original superset `S`, with `0 <= j < M`, such that for all elements `x in P_j`, every `x` has the same list of "parents" among the "original" sets `T_i`.

## Example

```
S = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6,   8, 9]

T_1 = [1, 4]
T_2 = [2, 3]
T_3 = [1, 3, 4]
```

So all `P_j`s would be:

```
P_1 = [1, 4] # all elements x have the same list of "parents": T_1, T_3
P_2 = [2] # all elements x have the same list of "parents": T_2
P_3 = [3] # all elements x have the same list of "parents": T_2, T_3
P_4 = [5, 6, 8, 9] #  all elements x have the same list of "parents": S (so they're not in any of the P_j
```

## Questions

1. What are good functions/classes in the python packages to compute all `P_j`s **and** the list of their "parents", ideally restricted to `numpy` and `scipy`? Perhaps there's already a function which does just that
2. What is the best algorithm to find those partitions `P_j`s **and** for each one, the list of "parents"? Let's note `T_0 = S`

*I think* the brute force approach would be to generate all 2-combinations of `T` sets and split them in at most 3 disjoint sets, which would be added back to the pool of `T` sets and then repeat the process until all resulting `T`s are disjoint, and thus we've arrived at our answer - the set of `P` sets. A little problematic could be caching all the "parents" on the way there.

*I suspect* a *dynamic programming* approach could be used to optimize the algorithm.

*Note: I would have **loved** to write the math parts in latex (via MathJax), but unfortunately this is not activated :-(*

Comment: The following may paint your imagination towards an answer to your question: http://www.geekviewpoint.com/java/bitwise/power_set. In your case you are already starting with the superset. But the logic there should help.

Comment: @kasavbere I already have that painting, but I don't want the powerset. The subsets are already given. It's basically a cathegorization problem.

Comment: `0 < i < n` gives only `n-1` sets.

Comment: `P4` should not contain `7`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following should be linear time (in the number of the elements in the `T`s).

```py
from collections import defaultdict

S = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6,   8, 9]

T_1 = [1, 4]
T_2 = [2, 3]
T_3 = [1, 3, 4]

Ts = [S, T_1, T_2, T_3]

parents = defaultdict(int)
for i, T in enumerate(Ts):
    for elem in T:
        parents[elem] += 2 ** i

children = defaultdict(list)
for elem, p in parents.items():
    children[p].append(elem)

print(list(children.values()))
```

Result:

```
[[5, 6, 8, 9], [1, 4], [2], [3]]
```

Comment: @Flavius, his solution does that. The keys of the children dict are the binary-encoded set of "parents". You could actually do it (elegantly, but perhaps not optimally efficiently) by using sets instead of integers.

Answer (score 1):

The way I'd do this is to construct an `M × n` boolean array `In` where `In(i, j) = Si ∈ Tj`. You can construct that in `O(Σj|Tj|)`, provided you can map an element of `S` onto its integer index in `O(1)`, by scanning all of the sets `T` and marking the corresponding bit in `In`.

You can then read the "signature" of each element `i` directly from `In` by concatenating row `i` into a binary number of `n` bits. The signature is precisely the equivalence relationship of the partition you are seeking.

By the way, I'm in total agreement with you about Math markup. Perhaps it's time to mount a new campaign.